# Print both in Android and pure Java

Tags: java, android

How to print both to Log.e/d/etc. and to System.out/err/etc.? I have some code that I test on desktop and sometimes I use it on Android and I want to see logs there too.

Comment: Have you tried java.util.logging API?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you give me some example?

Comment: Here's a random googled link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html . As far as I remember, it used to work.

Comment: I thought some one-lines will be enough... I will give it a try, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply use `System.out.println(tag+": "+msg);`, it should output to your console when you run the code in a regular Java app, and print to LogCat with the tag `System.out` when running from within Android.

Comment: I just tried it and it does. You have to explain a bit further without simply saying it doesn't, like explaining how you are using the source file in both scenarios.

Comment: My mistake, it works, and it even doesn't need "tag" inside println.

Comment: It doesn't, that is just to make it easier for you to spot them in LogCat, because your log statements from different source files will all have the same Logcat tag name as `System.out`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
/ Create a console handler
ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
```

// Add to logger 
   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany");
   logger.addHandler(handler);

Comment: And how do I print with this?